# Types definitions aren't loading when executing Jest tests

Tags: typescript, testing, jestjs, testing-library

I'm building an open-source library of test utilities which also includes custom tech matches. But when creating test files and running them, a lot of errors are being raised regarding type definitions.

Refer to the following errors when running `yarn test`[image]

The errors are related to two different type definitions, which are:

- `toBeVisible` is a custom Jest matcher that should come from `@testing-library/jest-dom`
- `toHaveQueryParam` is a custom Jest matcher created internally at my package and which I declared the definitions inside `@types/jest.d.ts` - This type definition should be loaded with [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), but I presume it's not working due to the errors.

My question is: Why the type definitions aren't loading? I presume that there should be something wrong regarding the TS compiler or Jest configs

[PR with the tests code](https://github.com/LauraBeatris/react-router-testing-utils/pull/3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very good question, I have run into this issue so many times. I use [`jest-extended`](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended) which says in their [readme](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#typescript) that you may need to import the type definitions in a `global.d.ts` file. Then add the `global.d.ts` file to the `typeRoots` in your `tsconfig.json`.

I also created my own jest matcher internal to my repo and add that file to my `typeRoots` as well.

A huge note is that all of this will still fail if these files are NOT included in your `tsconfig.json`. For example, you have a `global.d.ts` file but your `rootDir` is set to `src` (excluding the `global.d.ts`).

---

That said here is the [repo](https://github.com/elastic/elastic-charts) you can reference for a working example. Here is the [custom matcher](https://github.com/elastic/elastic-charts/blob/b4943e9b69ca3cef136da841c1091e10fa0099ec/scripts/custom_matchers.ts#L37-L47) type definitions, [global.d.ts](https://github.com/elastic/elastic-charts/blob/b4943e9b69ca3cef136da841c1091e10fa0099ec/global.d.ts#L20) importing `jest-extended` and [`tsconfig.json`](https://github.com/elastic/elastic-charts/blob/master/tsconfig.json#L22) `typeRoots` definition.

All in all I think you just need to add the custom types explicitly to the `compilerOptions`. And make sure to include your custom type files in your `tsconfig.json` file selection.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./**/*.d.ts", "./scripts/custom_matchers.ts"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Very descriptive answer :)